# In what type of web application where you should not use angular JS

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, vs-web-application-project

I know a reason like if you dont want to create SPA(Single page application) then you should not use angularjs.

I want to know other possible reasons for not using angularJS in a web application or the disadvantages of angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Not impossible, but it's hard to create social media capabilities(sharing) for pages which content is generated by angular. Social media robots do not render the page with javascript, and things like {{scope.my_content}} will end up in the shared text instead of the real content.

There are workarounds of course... https://prerender.io/ can help for example.